# If I want to search for an element in arraylist, what is the Big-Theta for that?

Tags: java, database, algorithm

I think I can sort the array first and then use binary search.
So the O(n^2).
Is that correct?

Comment: Or you can *not* sort the array, traverse it once and be done in O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think I can sort the array first and then use binary search. So the O(n^2). Is that correct?

The complexity of that approach would be O(nlogn) for the sort, and O(logn) for the binary search to do a lookup.  Overall O(nlogn).

The alternative is simple linear search lookup (e.g. using `contains` or a loop) which is O(n).

Sorting and using binary search is only going to give you better performance if you can amortize the (whole list) sort cost over a lot of lookups; i.e. sort once, search many times.

If you want better than linear search, you need to use a data structure that allows you to update the sorted structure<sup>1</sup> with better than O(nlogn) and search with better than O(n).
Finally ... if you do this:

- Sort the initial arraylist.
- Update the sorted arraylist by using binary search to find correct point for the insertion / removal.
- Use binary search for lookup.

You will end up with O(n) update operations (with the O(nlogn) sorting step amortized) and O(logn) lookup

---

In short, it is a complicated set of alternatives, and the best one will depend on the expected behavior of your application.

---

<sup>1 - A `TreeSet` would do that (modulo that it eliminates duplicates).  It uses a red-black binary tree under the hood.  And if your data is actually a set, then you should consider `HashSet` which gives you `O(1)` operations (unless the hash code function is pathological).</sup>

Comment: If the OP is happy to use a Set rather than a List, why not recommend `HashSet` rather than `TreeSet`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington - Good point.  The down-side is that you can't iterate in order.